# Retrieving a list with flex netConnection.call method

Tags: java, actionscript-3, red5

I was doing some tests with red5 and custom flex client with AS3, similar to the simple broadcaster they have on Flash with AS2.  But I added a function on the server

```
public List<String> listaCanales(){
        List<String> canales = new ArrayList<String>();
        canales.add("Canal 1");
        canales.add("Canal 2");
        canales.add("Canal 3");
        canales.add("Canal 4");
        canales.add("Canal x");
        return canales;
    }
```

This function is just a test, the idea is to retrive all the channels that I create on red5, the channels as scopes eventually.

I created a small function called add before and it works

```
public int add(int a, int b){
        return a+b;
    }
```

Here is how I called the add function

```
connection  = new NetConnection();
connection.connect("rtmp://"+servidor+"/"+red5App);
connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onConnected);
connection.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
var nr:Responder = new Responder(netResponderHandler);
connection.call("add", nr,5,6);
```

And it works with the add function, but when I try the listaCanales function it is like the netResponder handler is not working.

```
connection  = new NetConnection();
connection.connect("rtmp://"+servidor+"/"+red5App);
connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onConnected);
connection.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
var nr:Responder = new Responder(netResponderHandler);
connection.call("listaCanales", nr,null);
```

or

```
connection.call("listaCanales", nr);
```

Here is my netResponderHandler

```
protected function netResponderHandler(serverResult:Object):void
{   
    registros("Something happened");
    //registros("The result is " + serverResult);
}
```

Comment: post the listaCanales function

Answer (score 0):

When you say *I created a small function xzy* I asume that your test function is a a class that act as your "web.handler". So this function is inside a Class that extends the ApplicationAdapter of Red5.

If the Red5 server cannot handle the call (because it cannot map the request to a specific method in ApplicationAdapter) then you will see some log entry either in the red5 or error log file.

Did you check those logs?

Can you see the request when you increase the debug level in the conf/logback.xml from INFO to some higher level?

Also I wonder about your AS script, actually you should wait with the method call untill you received the connection-success method. Not just call all methods in one row. You have to code this event driven.
So in the "onconnect" handler you check => Connection Success. And then you continue with your program to call/test your methods.

Sebastian